# Android-Button acts like spinner

Tags: android, button, spinner, dropdown

Guys I need a button that will give me a dropdown list when I clicked.I mean it is going to act like spinner.Can anyone give me some useful source to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Popup menu to show the dropdown as shown in this example - http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

Answer (score 1):

You should go for **[PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)**

> A PopupMenu displays a Menu in a modal popup window anchored to a
>   View. The popup will appear below the anchor view if there is room, or
>   above it if there is not. If the IME is visible the popup will not
>   overlap it until it is touched. Touching outside of the popup will
>   dismiss it.

Check demo **[Android Popup Menu Example](http://javatechig.com/android/android-popup-menu-example)**